# AngularJS Express HTML5 IE9 redirect loop

Tags: angularjs, express, angularjs-routing

When Angular is executed in IE9 it falls back at legacy hashbang mode. What is the appropriate router setup both in Angular and Express so it works in IE9? Currently my app works fine in all browsers except IE9 and backward versions. Is there a solution in case the app is not running in the / but in a specific page?